# Make complex statistics with date

Tags: sql, hiveql

I'm using an imaginary problem in order to illustrate as this is sensitive data.

I have a large table counting how many people each city in a country count per month (a row per couple month, city)
I'd like to make an average of how many more or fewer people joined the city every month after a specific event occurred.

PROBLEM: that event didn't occur in the same month in every city.
Therefore, I can't just make general statistics based on a specific common date.

If the event occurred on dec 2018 in city A, and in apr 2019 in city B, I need Month 0 To be dec 18 for city A and April 19 for city B.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: You have a table with four columns: year, month, city, and people_count. There is one row per year, month, and city. But now you are talking about an event that took place in different cities at different times. Where can we see where and when the event took place? Is this simply one more column "event" in the table? Or is there another table listing all events that occured in a particular month and city?

Answer (score 0):

Solution that I came up with is "normalizing" dates. I added a new column called `relative_month`, which as calculated as follows :

`row_year` * 12 + `row_month` - `event_occured_year`*12 - `event_occured_month`

Therefore, each row is now labeled with what month it is relatively to the event, independently from the actual date.
`relative_month` is 0 on the month of the even. `relative_month` is -3 3 months before the event. `relative_month` is 12 1 year after the event for each city.

I was then able to make my charts by displaying the average of each values on relative months.

I hope this makes sense and helps whoever comes across the same problem.